# How to justify text width in latex like in a Word document

Tags: alignment, hyphenation, justification

I faced a problem that in LaTeX it is not a trivial thing to apply a text justification based on line width like in Word.

I have tried `\usepackage[hyphenate]{microtype}` and `\usepackage{ragged2e}` with `\justify` but that's not it: there is still a hyphenation. And when I set `\hyphenpenalty=10000` it just makes the lines out of the page bounds.

I want to have the text justification like it is in Word where there is no hyphenation and the words fill all line.

Thank you for your attention to my post!

Comment: why would you disable hyphenation?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - to make it look like a wretched MS Word document? :-)